# If string is present copy&paste row to new worksheet; Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to build code where if this string of characters is present then I want to copy the entire row of the active cell and paste it on to a new workbook.

This is what the column I am trying to filter sort of looks like:

[cells with 0 - multiple entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFEFe.png)

I keep getting an object-defined error that I am unsure how to resolve. Here is the code I am working with

```
Sub moveData(ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long, ByVal k As Long, ByVal row_sum As Double)

Worksheets("HHP").Range("BN").Select
' Change A2 to whatever cell you want the data to be copied to
Worksheets("FastTrackTool").Range("BN").Select

For i = 16 To row_sum
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell = "D0Y" Or "D0Z" Or "D1B" Or "D1C" Or "D1D" Or "D0M" Then
            MsgBox (ActiveCell)
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Worksheets("HHP").Select
        With Selection
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Worksheets("FastTrackTool").Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` is a Range object, so I don't think "D0Y" is valid for that comparison. I think you want `ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: I tried this, but I still come up with the same error

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: If the code is placed in a work, replace the code in a module

Comment: It doesn't actually tell me, but it does highlight

Comment: Worksheets("HHP").Range("BN").Select

Comment: the code is placed within a module

Comment: Did you mean` Worksheets("HHP").Range("B:N").Select`? (added a colon between the B and N)

Comment: Range("B:N") this would place my range between B and N wouldn't it? That is not what I want. I want the range of the row to extend to column "BN"

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate issues I can see with your code. The first problem is your IF statement.

```
If ActiveCell = "D0Y" Or "D0Z" Or "D1B" Or "D1C" Or "D1D" Or "D0M" Then
```

The OR doesn't work like this - you need a condition to check between each OR, and it needs to evaluate to True or False. I fixed this in the code below, though [there is an even better, much more concise way to do it with a Select Case statement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147722/excel-vba-in-a-list-if-cell-equals-specific-value-then)

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "D0Y" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D0Z" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1B" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1C" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1D" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D0M" Then
```

The other problem is that you are trying to compare the Range object as Jacob H mentioned. If you would like to compare that cell's *value*, then use the .Value attribute/member (terminology?) to access this. There are two instances of this mistake, which I also fixed in the below code.

NOTE: One instance might not actually be a mistake - I changed the MsgBox(ActiveCell) to MsgBox(ActiveCell.Value). However, you may have intended it to pop up with the address (ActiveCell.Address), or some other attribute.

### Your code, with my noted revisions:

```
Sub moveData(ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long, ByVal k As Long, ByVal row_sum As Double)

Worksheets("HHP").Range("BN").Select
' Change A2 to whatever cell you want the data to be copied to
Worksheets("FastTrackTool").Range("BN").Select

For i = 16 To row_sum
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        If ActiveCell.Value = "D0Y" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D0Z" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1B" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1C" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D1D" Or ActiveCell.Value = "D0M" Then
            MsgBox (ActiveCell.Value)
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Worksheets("HHP").Select
        With Selection
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Worksheets("FastTrackTool").Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next

End Sub
```

I haven't tested this code, but those are the issues that pop out to me. Let me know if this fixes your error.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: thank you! I forgot to change the if statement and I missed that second instance of ActiveCell.Value, I will let you know how it goes

Comment: No such luck, still coming up with error 1004. I will have to look at it at a later time

Comment: If you attach your workbook, maybe I can do a little manual troubleshooting to discover the problem. One trick is to put a 'break' into the code, then hit F8 each time you want the next line to run. That way, you can tell exactly what each line of the code does and where things are going haywire.